# What is the process by which an already passed law can be altered by Congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislation

To clarify, I'm not talking about the rules used to clarify legislation after it is passed.

For instance, since the CFAA (Computer Fraud and Abuse Act) has already been signed into law, what is the process a congressperson would go through to have the text of that legislation altered?

My initial thought was that it was just an amendment, but if that is the case, what is the procedural difference between an amendment proposed before the bill leaves the chamber, versus the process of amending an already enacted law?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congress would pass a bill to either amend, repeal, or add to existing statutes.

They can never change what the original bill said when it was passed, but they can change what the law will be going forward.

An example is the [House Page Board Revision Act](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/PLAW-110publ2/html/PLAW-110publ2.htm) (2007), which amended the composition of the House of Representatives Page Board, initially established by statute in 1983.